# Proxmox sets the same MAC to the bridge

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge, proxmox

I have three nodes in a Proxmox cluster under a Cisco Switch. When I sniff the traffic with an external PC I observe that when pinging from one node to the other the packets are duplicated.

/etc/network/interfaces of the nodes look like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s31f6 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 10.81.59.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.81.59.1
bridge_ports enp0s31f6
bridge_ageing 0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
hwaddress ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

And when I get into the nodes I observe that:

$ brctl showmacs vmbr0

```
18:66:da:31:ba:92
18:66:da:31:ba:92
```

In summary, I try to force changing the bridge HW address but it never changes it so I have the same MAC for enp0s31f6 and vmbr0 what provokes the duplication of packets.

How can I modify the MAC address of the node in Proxmox?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific option for setting mac addresses of bridge devices:

[`bridge_hw`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bridge-utils/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.en.html)

Caveat:

> "[...] you should know what you are doing before using this option."